# How to get GCM notification in android from youtube whenever changes in subscribe channel

Tags: android, youtube, google-cloud-messaging

How to get GCM notification from youtube when a comment is added, a video is added, a playlist is created in subscribed channel. I have implemented GCM in my android app.I want add user GCM registration key in youtube so I will get push notification from youtube whenever changes in subscribed channel.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a server running that pushes notifications to your devices. That server should push those updates to the devices when there is an update about a channel. I'm pretty sure it is not possible to set a GCM registration key on youtube.

Youtube does support [Adhook subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) to get updates about a channel. Unfortunately for you, this does not include subscription changes, according to the documentation. So you would need to pull that information from youtube on a particular interval using [this youtube api endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).